# Trying to use laravel pagination breaks my controller/view

Tags: pagination, laravel, eloquent, laravel-3

I'm trying to get Pagination working in Laravel. I've not used pagination before so am trying to use some examples from the docs and google results. I'm wondering if I need to turn 'pagination' on somewhere in config.

Here's my simple working controller:

```
public function get_index() {
  $locations = Location::all();
  return View::make('location.index')->with('locations', $locations)->render();
}
```

When I try and add pagination like this it breaks:

```
public function get_index() {
  $locations = Location::paginate(5);
  return View::make('location.index')->with('locations', $locations)->render();
}
```

..and I get the error:

```
Unhandled Exception

Message:
Error rendering view: [location.index]

Trying to get property of non-object
```

Here's my location.index view:

```
@layout('layouts.blank')
@section('content')
<div class="row">
<div class="twelve columns">
    <div role="main" id="content">
        <h3>Locations - All</h3>
        @if($locations)
            <table class="twelve">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th style="text-align: left;">Address</th>
                        <th>Area</th>
                        <th>Region</th>
                        <th>Edit</th>
                        <th>Delete</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                @foreach($locations as $location)
                <tbody> 
                    <tr>
                        <td style="text-align: left;">{{ $location->company,', ',$location->add_name,', ',$location->add_city }}</td>
                        <td> – </td>
                        <td> – </td>
                        <td>{{ HTML::link('location/update/'.$location->id, '',array('class'=>"foundicon-edit updateicon")) }}</td>
                        <td>{{ HTML::link('location/delete/'.$location->id, '',array('class'=>"foundicon-remove warnicon")) }}</td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
                @endforeach
            </table>
        @else
          Looks like we haven't added any locations, yet!
        @endif
        <p>{{ HTML::link('location/create', 'Create a location', array('class'=>"small radius button")) }}</p>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
@endsection
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hadn't read deeply enough into the subject. It's now working and here's what I had to change in the view:

```
//from:
@foreach($locations as $location)

//to:
@foreach($locations->results as $location)
```

That returned just 5 results. Then to add links to the footer of my table I added this HTML/Blade:

```
<tfoot>
  <tr>
    <td colspan="5"> {{ $locations->links() }} </td>
  </tr>
</tfoot>
```

Hope someone else benefits as I didn't find this terribly clear in the docs.